# Resizing base64 encoded image in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation, base64

The following function works perfectly for me with Chrome and Firefox, while it fails with Internet Explorer. I added the the the obj_* assignments to debug it in IE, the .height() or .width methods do not work.
Is the jpgmulti stream not usable for IE? Do I have to call it different for IE? Below is confirmed working with Chrome and FF on MacOSX.

```
function append-base64image(jpgmulti) {
      var object = jQuery.parseJSON('{'+jpgmulti+'}');
      for (var content in object) {
        // create element for image    
        var image_roll = document.createElement("img");
        // ad attributes to element
        image_roll.setAttribute("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+object[content]);
          // calculate aspect ratio for preview:
          var obj_height = object[content].height;
          var obj_width = object[content].width;
      var div_obj_width = obj_width/150;
          var height_resize = obj_height/div_obj_width;
          image_roll.setAttribute("width", 150);
          image_roll.setAttribute("height", height_resize);
          document.getElementById("previews").appendChild(image_roll);
      }
 }
```